# run python script from a .bat file and using Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, batch-file

I run several python scripts on my W10 server and I'm looking for a way to open them all together.

I run manually my scripts opening a PowerShell on the script folder and executing `pythonw script.py`

I have tried several ways, with no result...

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\Users\pc2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pythonw.exe C:\Users\pc2\script.py'"
```

also tested:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command "'pythonw C:\Users\pc2\script.py'"
```

And:

```
powershell -command "& {&'C:\Users\pc2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pythonw.exe ' C:\Users\pc2\script.py}"
```

None of the above does anything... they should be opening the script.py file in using pythonw.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To execute a *single* script:

  ```
  powershell -c "pythonw 'C:\Users\pc2\script1.py'"
  ```

<sup>Note: The enclosing `'...'` around the file path are only needed if the latter contains shell metacharacters such as whitespace.

Alternatively,
 use `""...""` when calling from `cmd.exe` (batch file), and `` `"...`" ``
 when calling from PowerShell.</sup>

- To execute *multiple* scripts, *in sequence*:

  ```
  powershell -c "& { $Args | % { pythonw $_ } } 'C:\Users\pc2\script1.py' 'C:\Users\pc2\script2.py'"
  ```

<sup>Note: This only works when calling from `cmd.exe` (batch file).

(From within PowerShell, simply execute what's inside `"..."` directly)</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**, focusing just on what command string PowerShell ended up seeing:

- `& 'C:\Users\pc2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pythonw.exe C:\Users\pc2\script.py'`

The problem is that you're passing the entire command line to `&`, whereas it only expects the *executable* name;
 `C:\Users\pc2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pythonw.exe C:\Users\pc2\script.py` is obviously not a valid executable name / path.

- `'pythonw C:\Users\pc2\script.py'`

By virtue of being enclosed in `'...'`, this is a *string literal*, which PowerShell simply *outputs* as such - no *command* is ever executed.

- `& {&'C:\Users\pc2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pythonw.exe ' C:\Users\pc2\script.py}`

Since you're using a *script block* (`{ ... }`), you're passing `C:\Users\pc2\script.py` as an *argument*, so you'd have to refer to it as such inside the block, either via the automatic `$Args` variable, or via a parameter defined in a `param()` block.
(As an aside: your file path has an extraneous trailing space, but PowerShell seems to ignore that.)

Comment: The first one works, but the second i get an error. when i excecute i get ....C:\Users\pc2\Desktop>powershell -c "& { $Args | \Users\pc2\4.py'" "'C:\Users\pc23.py'" "'C:\Users\pc2\2.py'"  "'C:\Users\pc2\1.py'"
Missing chain at the end: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: @user8459020: Your command's syntax differs from my solution; however, I've since simplified the approach by using a _single_ double-quoted string to pass to PowerShell, with single-quoted strings inside. Unless you can find a problem with the code as posted (replace `pythonw` with `Write-Host` to verify that the script paths are passed), I suggest you ask a _new_ question, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From the powershell console itself, you can directly run like this:

```
PS C:\Python27> python C:\Users\pc2\script.py
```

If necessary please edit the **PATHTEXT** environmental variable in the powershell profile:

```
$env:PATHEXT += ";.py"
```

In the batch also you can put the same command to execute the python. Save the file as something.bat :

```
python C:\Users\pc2\script.py
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: the idea is not to open a powershell, but to have a .bat file launch all the scrips..

Comment: @user8459020: In the batch file, you can keep the same command to execute the py script.

Comment: but i need the Batch file, to excecute Powershell and then the scripst